# Order django query result by number of Q() OR matches

Tags: python, django

I have a lot of Q() OR conditions in a queryset, and need to order the queryset based on how many of those Q() were matches. For example:

```
def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):

    word = self.request.GET.get('q') # from search input

    # get objects with word in title, description or body
    q_objects = Q() 
    q_objects |= Q(title__icontains=word)
    q_objects |= Q(description__icontains=word)
    q_objects |= Q(body__icontains=word)

    qs = super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
    qs = qs.filter(q_objects)
    return qs
```

This returns a queryset list of all objects that have **word** in *title* *description* or *body*. But what I want is to order the queryset list by how many Q() filters were a match. If an object had **word** in all 3 fields, that should be listed first, then fields with **word** in 2 fields, and so forth. My first thought was to somehow add an annotate() to each Q() that increments, and sorting by that. But I'm not sure that's possible with Q() and annotate. Does anyone know how I could achieve this?

Comment: are you looking for stemming and ranking the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django's aggregate functions accept a filter [argument](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/aggregation/) (see the cheat sheet).  We can reuse the Q objects you already created as filters to count how many times those filters occurred.  See each of the individual annotations that counted the filters.

Then sum those filter counts and order_by the sum.

I haven't tested this code so I hope it works for you.

```
from django.db.models import Count    

def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
    qs = super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)

    word = self.request.GET.get('q')  # from search input

    title = Q(title__icontains=word)
    description = Q(description__icontains=word)
    body = Q(body__icontains=word)

    filters = title | description | body

    qs = (qs
          .filter(filters)
          .annotate(title_filter_cnt=Count('id', filter=title))
          .annotate(description_filter_cnt=Count('id', filter=description))
          .annotate(body_filter_cnt=Count('id', filter=body))
          .annotate(total_filter_cnt=F('title_filter_cnt') +
                                     F('description_filter_cnt') +
                                     F('body_filter_cnt'))
          .order_by('total_filter_cnt'))

    return qs
```

Comment: Tested this and it works, I like that it's all being done on the queryset. Thank you!

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for and tried using the doc but im fairly new to Django and it was a bit hard to wrap my head around it. But this explains it much more clearly for me, thank you. 

I would like to dig a little further into this, and explore more of what can be done, is there a tutorial or any other page other than the docs you could recommend?

Answer (score 0):

My solution is complex, but hopefully it will solve your problem,

```
def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
    q_ordered = []

    word = self.request.GET.get('q') # from search input

    # get objects with word in title, description or body
    q_objects = Q() 

    q_in_title          = Q(title__icontains=word)
    q_in_description    = Q(description__icontains=word)
    q_in_body           = Q(body__icontains=word)

    q_objects           |= Q(title__icontains=word)
    q_objects           |= Q(description__icontains=word)
    q_objects           |= Q(body__icontains=word)

    q_ordered += [obj for obj in q_objects if obj in q_in_title and obj in q_in_description and obj in q_in_body]

    q_ordered += [obj for obj in q_objects if ( obj in q_in_title and obj in q_in_description ) or ( obj in q_in_description and obj in q_in_body ) or ( obj in q_in_title and obj in q_in_body)]

    q_ordered += [obj for obj in q_objects if obj in q_in_title or obj in q_in_description or obj in q_in_body]

    qs = super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
    qs = qs.filter(q_ordered)
    return qs
```

also you can use

```
    for obj in q_objects:
        if obj in q_in_title and obj in q_in_description and obj in q_in_body:
            q_ordered += obj

    for obj in q_objects:
        if ( obj in q_in_title and obj in q_in_description ) or ( obj in q_in_description and obj in q_in_body ) or ( obj in q_in_title and obj in q_in_body):
            q_ordered += obj

    for obj in q_objects:
        if obj in q_in_title or obj in q_in_description or obj in q_in_body:
            q_ordered += obj
```

Instead of using

```
    q_ordered += [obj for obj in q_objects if obj in q_in_title and obj in q_in_description and obj in q_in_body]

    q_ordered += [obj for obj in q_objects if ( obj in q_in_title and obj in q_in_description ) or ( obj in q_in_description and obj in q_in_body ) or ( obj in q_in_title and obj in q_in_body)]

    q_ordered += [obj for obj in q_objects if obj in q_in_title or obj in q_in_description or obj in q_in_body]
```